# Specifying coqtop path for CoqIDE Vim plugin on Windows 8.1

Tags: vim, plugins, windows-8.1, coq, coqide

I am trying to make the [CoqIDE Vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4388) work on Windows 8.1. When I source the plugin from Vim, I get this error message:

```
coqtop.opt: command not found.
```

So I looked up the plugin documentation, and found the part that seems relevent:

```
"coqtop" should be accessible on PATH. If "coqtop" is not in your PATH, add 'let CoqIDE_coqtop = "/path/to/coqtop"' in your "~/.vimrc".
```

I'm not sure what this means, but I'm guessing that there is some file or directory named `coqtop` that must be made visible to vim. So I opened my Coq installation directory and searched for `coqtop`. The search hits are:

```
coqtop
coqtop.cmi
coqtop.1
coqtop.byte.1
coqtop.opt.1
```

The obvious first candidate here is `coqtop`. When I click it, it opens an interactive Coq console. But when I use the `let CoqIDE_coqtop` command to link this file to Vim and load the plugin again, I get:

```
C:Program Files (x86)Coq^Hincoqtop.exe: command not found.
```

Another thing that looks problematic is the file type. As you can see from the error message above, the `coqtop` file has an `.exe` extension, which is specific to MS-DOS and Windows. But I don't think the plugin was written to work with `.exe` files...

I also tried using all the other search hits as `coqtop`, to no avail.

Does this mean that the plugin is useless on Windows? If someone can confirm that I'll just give up and use other IDEs. But if possible I'd really, really like to keep using Vim.

Comment: How about asking the plugin's author for help?!

Comment: B.t.w., Windows accepts slashes (/) instead of backslashes (\\) in paths.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: I guess that's the best option at this point. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @autorewrite: Your suggestion actually partially works. I've been inadvertently using slashes by copying Windows paths. I changed them to backslashes and now Vim gets to the point where it opens up the Coq console and attempts to communicate with it. It still freezes there, but it's an improvement.